# Does age affect a Transformer's healing (repairing) capacity?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

In humans, the younger heal faster than the elderly. Is this also the case with Transformers?

Is there any evidence that younger Autobots/Decpticons heal (repair?!) quicker than their older friends?

I came up with this question from this post on a discussion regarding Bumblebee's recovery after the events of the first *Transformers* film. Bumblebee loses his legs in the first film, and yet is completely healed in the second part. However, Jazz, doesn't quite recover from a similar fate.

Also, in *Revenge of The Fallen* we can see that JetFire is in a really bad shape, seemingly because of his age.

The link to the discussion: [How did Bumblebee heal after the events of Transformers the film.](http://www.shootfortheedit.com/forum/showthread.php?3730-How-did-they-repair-Bumblebee&s=4c4c028189e2425bcbb0f3465a69f127&p=64210&viewfull=1#post64210)

Comment: You mean like Jetfire in *Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen*, who is basically falling apart as he's walking? ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar - Thanks a lot! I'll add it to the question.. I had a feeling I was forgetting something....

Comment: It seems that their metallic body rusts out in long time..

Comment: That seems logical. But they aren't made of Iron to rust... But I get your point. But what I'm really curious about is, are younger Transformers more capable of healing(repairing)?

Comment: @ash_k29: The point I was making with my reference to Jetfire is, there's your "evidence" of age affecting Transformers, right there. Besides, any kind of metal or alloy "ages", and quite some tend to oxydize. It's not just iron that's rusting, failure of electronic components completely aside.

Comment: @DevSolar - yes. But does that mean younger autobots can heal better? Does that mean Bumblebee could've been fine after hibernating like JetFire did?

Comment: I'd imagine Bumblebee would need still need to be repaired after the Battle of Mission City. Even at the beginning of the film, Ratchet is said to have been actively working on repairing his voice box. Jetfire is regarded by the "younger" TF's as "ancient". It's possible that between the time Jetfire and the current generation were created, the parts/materials making up Transformers slightly changed.

Answer (score 3):

It does. There is lack of evidence in the movies (and in the comics), since the healing process for a transformer is unclear.

Nevertheless, by the research you have done to get to that discussion, you probably know a little bit about the [Transformers' healing process](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/26t203/transformers_how_are_the_transformers_able_to/) and about [Transformers' technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_technology).

Since the Transformers are  mechanical but living creatures (techno-organic?), their parts (the nanobots that act like their healing or immune system) and processes (programming and data) are subject to decay with time, thus **becoming less efficient**.

Of course their technology is highly advanced, so they have extraordinary lifespans, and highly efficient healing/auto-reparing capabilities. It wouldn't be until a Transformer is really old or gets seriously damaged that this process should get affected. When their own auto-healing mechanism is not enough, or to keep it in shape, they need to rely on their doctors, such as Ratchet.